# use javascript and geojson to create feature layer for mapbox map

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, mapbox, geojson

I have a mapbox map in my Ruby on Rails app, and I'd like to populate a feature layer with point coordinates from my database. I can't seem to find meaningful help on this on the Mapbox website. I found a website that offered a guide, but it skips steps that must have been obvious to the author, but aren't to me. Can anyone help me do this?

Here's what I have. In the Index method of my Productions controller, I've created a geojson array (the indentation here is screwed up, but it's correct in the actual file):

```
  def index

# to place all productions on map
@productionsall = Production.all
@geojson = Array.new

@productionsall.each do |p|
@geojson << {
  type: 'Feature',
  geometry: {
    type: 'Point',
    coordinates: [p.longitude, p.latitude]
  },
  properties: {
    name: p.company,
    address: p.full_address,
    :'marker-color' => '#00607d',
    :'marker-symbol' => 'circle',
    :'marker-size' => 'medium'
  }
}
end
respond_to do |format|
  format.html
  format.json { render json: @geojson }  # respond with the created JSON object
end
end
```

Then on the Index page, I've got the map itself and an attempt at a function (borrowed from a Stack Overflow answer) to add a layer:

```
<div id='map'></div>
<script>
  L.mapbox.accessToken = 'xxxxx';

  var map = L.mapbox.map('map', 'example.idkeiso')
    .setView([41.344,-99.316], 5);

  var zipLayer;

  $.getJSON('production/index.json', function(data) {
      zipLayer = L.mapbox.featureLayer(data);
      zipLayer.addTo(map);
  });

</script>
```

The map appears, but without any markers.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: First thing first: check if there are any errors and confirm that production/index.json is well-formed geojson.  A [geojson validator](http://geojsonlint.com/) might be helpful.  Otherwise, hard to tell what's going on here.

Comment: Thank you! Unfortunately, I don't quite get the instructions on the geojson validator for "programmatic access," which seems to be what I need. Sigh, I wish Mapbox would just include instructions on how to do this! In case it's helpful, what's "going on here" is that I'm cycling through all of my productions, each of which has a longitude and a latitude, and storing all of those points in an array called geojson. Then what I want to do is to call that array and create a feature layer for my mapbox map. I'm pretty sure it's the second batch of code that's not working, but not 100%.

Comment: No, no need for 'programmatic access'.  In your js, you are loading the index.json file: `$.getJSON('production/index.json', function(data) {`.  Is your rails app outputting the `production/index.json` file, and if so, does it contain the data you expect it to?  And does your browser console contain errors when you load the page?